# Liquid splatter in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit

Let's say a certain type of enemies could explode, and liquid ( blood / acid ) could hit nearby objects: player, enemies, boxes...

In Fruit Ninja splatter goes to background, which is easy. Here it goes on multiple sides, but not on Z axis, because it's a 2D game.

Is there an easy way to generate random liquid splatter on those object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no "easy way", mainly because how it would work and how it would affect the game is not exactly generalizable.  For instance, what does it mean for blood to hit the player?  Does it change a sprite?  A bunch of layered sprites?  A spritesheet?  Is the blood permanent or temporary?  Does it accumulate, or is it just "bloodied or not bloodied"?  Does the angle it hits the target matter?  What about if it doesn't hit a target - do players walking through it start leaving bloody footprints behind?  Etc.

If you want functionality like that, you're almost certainly going to have to custom code it.

What I would probably do is generate a bunch of particle-like sprite objects with randomly-generated blood spatter sprites, angle them away from the source, and animate them away from the source using SKActions or physics.  Then I'd check for them colliding with whatever screen elements I wanted them to be able to interact with, and when that happens, I'd kill the sprite and send a message to the thing that is bloodied and do whatever I need to in order to respond to that event to make the hit object look like it has been bloodied, like swapping out a "clean" spritesheet for a "bloodied" one.  If the sprite doesn't hit something before it finishes its animation, then I'd just leave it where it lands.

A cheaper, simpler solution would be to simply trigger a bunch of blood particles using the SpriteKit particle system, and add a random circular "blood splash" image into the scene.  Then, you just check if anything is within that radius, and if so, call it bloodied.  This would require having enough blood particles to make it look like anything getting that close would get splashed, but it would be much more straightforward than tracking individual particles and detecting collisions.